# npm start - script not found ?

Tags: macos, react-native, npm

I was reading this article >

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/building-mobile-apps-using-react-native-wordpress/

and wanted to try it out, and I got as far >

```
cd react-native-woo
npm start
```

And my mac is throwing this error...

```
Happy hacking!
Babylon7:desktop magic$ cd react-native woo
Babylon7:react-native magic$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/magic/.npm/_logs/2018-08-29T00_47_08_644Z-debug.log
Babylon7:react-native magic$
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not add a start script to the scripts property of the package.json file.

Something like:

```
"scripts":{
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Where `index.js` = your main sever file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you typed "npm start" in folder which has package.json? I am sorry if I am wrong,I am seeing you are changing directory react-native woo which is weird.